# memory efficient structure to track a subset of an array in its original order

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am using C# however I don't think this is a language specific question.

I am working on the data structure to track a subset of a large array. For example, I have a changing array of characters and I want to track the vowels in it. I want to track them in such a way that their original order is maintained.

To illustrate, let's say the character array currently is: [A, B, D, C, I, A, E, F]. The vowels subset I want will be [A, I, A, E]. If after a while the character array is changed to [T, B, D, C, I, A, E, F] (the first element has changed from A to T), the vowels subset will then become [I, A, E].

The vowels subset will be frequently random-accessed as if it is an array:  vowels[0], vowels[3] ... etc.

I can therefore summarize the features required for my data structure:

1) memory efficient - both the underlying array and the subset can be large. I am benchmarking a million entries.

2) the original order of the elements in the underlying array must be maintained in the subset.

3) fast random access speed. I will use the subset in the same way as using an array.

4) deletion and insertion needs to be efficient. I have change notification on the underlying array - eg. when the i-th character in the underlying array has changed, i will get a notification saying "i-th element has changed from A to B". However I need to insert or delete the corresponding item in the subset

5) **if it is going to make a difference, I prefer faster deletion and I can give up the performance of insertion.** The nature of our application has showed me that insertion on the subset is much less frequent than deletion, and it usually happens at the tail. But deletion, which can happen a lot, is always in the head or middle portion of the subset.

PS. I have seen a smart way for fast deletion of array element: keep a counter of how many elements are in the array. When deleting an element, swap it with the last element in the array and reduce the counter. It makes the deletion an O(1) operation. Although it will waste some memory by not shrinking the array, but I am satisfied since the data structure is only an array - it is compact enough. **The only issue with this approach is: it violates requirement (2). The order of element in the subset will be changed from its original when a deletion occurs.**

Edit:
After reading several answers, I realize I can ask the question in a more interesting way (at least I think it is more interesting :) ):

I definitely agree that a counted B-tree would be a working solution. But I don't need to support:
1) element look-up. e.g. I don't need to find where is the first 'A' in my subset
2) I don't need any sorting. All I want is to keep the original order.

It appears **I don't need any comparison of the element at all**. I know most of the sorted data structures are based on element comparison. I know that is why the optimal complexity is O(log n). I am wondering whether it is possible to improve the complexity of any of the three operations(random access, insertion, deletion), or reduce the memory complexity, if I don't need any comparison?

Comment: What percentage of the character array do you expect to be vowels?

Comment: the character array is just an example. The subset/underlying ratio varies. It actually depends on what our application's user is trying to do. Therefore although I know I can probably achieve some performance benefit if i can make an assumption on the data distribution, I would like to find a more generalized solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a [order statistic balanced binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) as it maintains order of elements and also supports insertion and deletion in `O(logn)`. All operations lookup, insertion and deletion are `O(logn)`.

**Algorithm :-**

```
1. store required values in tree as <index,vowel> pairs 
2. keep index as key for tree node.
3. You can lookup nth element in tree in O(logn)
4. You can delete element in O(logn)
5. You can insert element in O(logn)
6. Space requirement is O(n) with extra memory for size variables
```

Comment: Thanks. The link looks helpful. We indeed have implemented such a counting B-tree. But it is used only when a more fancy sorting is required. However i am wondering that if I do not need element lookup and comparison-based sorting, is that possible to either further reduce the memory footprint or make index-based access linear?

Comment: You would need sorting in this one as your array is changing after each insert and delete and you want to sort the vowels in the order of their index in array ?. lookup is just a extra benefit of the DS but removing lookup cannot decrease the space complexity.